Problem - Requesting Java AST from selection in Eclipse
When I start a new workspace in Eclipse, I started a new Java file in a simple Java application. When O try to start to edit a Java file in Eclipse, "Request Java AST from selection" is popup, as below:
Error Message
Please help me how to fix it in Eclipse and make it disappeared.
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 14.0.1+7
Java version: 14.0.1

Which version of Eclipse is it, and which version of Java is running it?

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 14.0.1+7
Java version: 14.0.1

The download of that now two year old release came with its own version of Java. Java 14 is also not a long-term supported release; can you retry it with either the version from the downloadable package, or another Java 11? And post the contents of the Details that are hidden in the image?

Eclipse 2022-06 is now 2 years and 8 releases old, any fix for this problem would be in a newer release. Can you please try the current Eclipse 2024-06
